# Inclusion of Lp into L1 on bounded domains using Holder inequal

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

On bounded domains, $L^p \subset L^1, p>1$ because on such domains a function isn't integrable if the function is too large. Exponentiating the function makes it larger.

Is it possible to show that $L^1(a,b)$ space is a more general space than $L^p(a,b),p>1$ using Holder inequality (below)?

$$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g(x)|dx \leq \Big(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^pdx\Big)^{1/p} \Big(\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)|^qdx\Big)^{1/q}$$

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to show $L^p(a,b)\subset L^1(a,b)$ using Holder's inequality?

Comment: carmichael561, yes and how to show it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f\in L^p(a,b)$ with $p>1$, then using Holder's inequality with $f$ and $1$ we get
$$ \int_a^b|f(x)|\;dx\leq\Big(\int_a^b|f(x)|^p\;dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big(\int_a^b\;dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{q}}=(b-a)^{\frac{1}{q}}||f||_p $$
Therefore $f\in L^1(a,b)$, and in fact
$$ ||f||_1\leq (b-a)^{\frac{1}{q}}||f||_p$$

Comment: carmichael561, so because $f\in L^p(a,b)$  the $||f||_p$ is finite and from Holder's inequality $||f||_1$ is finite as well ($f\in L^1(a,b)$)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: carmichael561, thank you very much for your reply